# Keeping elements in ViewController when ViewController is changed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am making a simple game and I have faced a problem. I have a UIButton that stops the game and changes GameViewController to a secondViewController. I have another UIButton in the secondViewController and when it's clicked, it goes back to the GameViewController. I have set those buttons via my storyboard so no coding.. The problem is when I go back to GameViewController from secondViewController, the game settings/data and anything else are set back to what they were. For example, I have 3 lives and if I lose one life and click on the button in gameViewController and go back to gameviewController, I will have 3 lives again.. How can I fix this problem? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your state when your game goes away, and load the saved state when your view loads again. You can save your state in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, and load the saved state in -viewWillAppear:, for example.